# Postgresql -- join syntax 'bug' that actually ran

Tags: postgresql, join, syntax

I noticed I wrote a query like this, the day after I wrote it:

```
SELECT
T1.col1,  
T2.col1,
T3.col1 
FROM our_schema.table1 T1 
INNER JOIN our_schema.table2 T2 
LEFT JOIN our_schema.table3  T3 ON (T2.id1 = T3.id1)
ON( (T1.id1 = T2.id1) 
ORDER BY T1.col1
```

It actually ran, despite the "ON" for the first JOIN being after the LEFT JOIN.

I really meant to run it as:

```
SELECT
T1.col1,  
T2.col1,
T3.col1 
FROM our_schema.table1 T1 
INNER JOIN our_schema.table2 T2 ON( (T1.id1 = T2.id1) 
LEFT JOIN our_schema.table3  T3 ON (T2.id1 = T3.id1)
ORDER BY T1.col1
```

Note:  The difference is where the ON clause is placed.

Surprisingly, the corrected version also runs but gives different results.

I would assume that the second query is the 'normal' way to do joins in PostgreSQL.

Can anyone explain what is going on in the first query and what is the difference between the two.
I'm surprised the first query didn't cause a compiler error.

Comment: Yes, that does answer the question.